# ThreadPoolExecutor and Socket. Thread isn't started

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, threadpool, pool

I have a class class with main thread

```
public class MainThread extends Thread
{
   private final Socket s;

   public MainThread(final Socket s)
   {
      this.s = s;
   }

public void start()  
{ // some logic 
}  
}
```

and class with pool of threads

```
public final class MainListener extends Thread
{

   private Socket ss;

   public MainListener(final int socket)
   {
      this.socket = socket;
      this.pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
         2,
         4,
         1000L,
         TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
         new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
   }  

public void start()
   {  
final ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(socket);
while(true)
{  
    final Socket s = ss.accept();
    pool.execute(new MainThread(s));
}
}
```

MainThread is created but not started. It is 'waiting'.
What is the problem? How start this thread after creation?
if I make constructor of MainThread like

```
public MainThread(final Socket s)
   {
      this.s = s;
      start();
   }
```

then all works normally. But it's wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've overridden `start` instead of `run`. To avoid making this mistake again, always use `Runnable`.

Comment: ...or always override run instead of start.

Comment: Yeah but if you use Runnable, trying to `@Override` start will result in a compilation error...

Comment: ...or always use `Runnable` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The `ThreadPoolExecutor` creates its *own* threads to run the tasks on... otherwise they wouldn't be pooled! The point of using an executor is to avoid creating and starting your own thread.

You should be implementing `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`. The `ThreadPoolExecutor` will then call your `run()` method on the pooled thread.

Even when you *do* create threads, it's almost always better to create a `Runnable` to pass to the `Thread` constructor rather than extending `Thread` directly.